# Изменения цвета подписи в картах яндекса с изменением типа карты

Tags: яндекс-карты, карты, координаты

Как изменить цвет подписи иконки в яндекс карте с изменением типы карты? Например, при переходе на спутник, иначе черный цвет плохо читается на темном фоне космоса.

https://jsfiddle.net/sz798m21/

По существу необходимо задать динамическое изменение для этого кода, если я правильно понимаю.

```
   MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div style="color: #000; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
    ),
```

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего использовать глобальную переменную CSS. Например

```css
:root {
    --map-icon-color: #000;
}
```

Её можно использовать в шаблоне иконки

```js
   MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div style="color: var(--map-icon-color); font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
    ),
```

А при необходимости - менять

```js
function setMapIconColor(color) {
    document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--map-icon-color', color);
}
```

Comment: Не поможете поправить код?, не могу понять почему за функцию не цепляется. Я всего 3 месяца как учусь, мне не хватает опыта :/  https://jsfiddle.net/s1q842dg/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r3mk7t4y/ функцию нужно определить глобально, а не в ymaps.ready

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Comment: Тогда отметьте ответ как принятый.